# iOS: I need a better way to write this piece of code that changes the label fontSize (bold and regular)

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, refactoring

Basically I have a way to check different position (newPostion), when a certain postion is met I bold certain labels as you can see below.However, this seems like quite a lot of code. Is there a better way to do this? I need refactor this to look better, but I don't know where to even begin.

```
 if(newPosition == 100){

    self.label.font = [utilClass boldFontWithSize:12];
    self.label1.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label2.font  = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label3.font =    [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label4.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];

}

else if(newPosition == 200){

    self.label.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label1.font = [utilClass boldFontWithSize:12];
    self.label2.font  = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label3.font =    [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label4.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
}
else if (newPosition == -100) {

    self.label.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label1.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label2.font  = [utilClass boldFontWithSize:12];
    self.label3.font =    [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label4.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];

}

else (newPosition == -200) {

    self.label.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label1.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label2.font  = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
    self.label3.font =    [utilClass boldFontWithSize:12];
    self.label4.font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
UIFont *font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
UIFont *bold = [utilClass boldFontSize:12];

self.label.font = font;
self.label1.font = font;
self.label2.font = font;
self.label3.font = font;
self.label4.font = font;

if (newPosition == 100) {
    self.label.font = boldFont;
} else if (newPosition == 200) {
    self.label1.font = boldFont;
} else if (newPosition == -100) {
    self.label2.font = boldFont;
} else if (newPosition == -200) {
    self.label3.font = boldFont;
}
```

This avoids a lot of the redundant code.

This could be made a lot easier if you had an array of labels instead of separate ivars.

```
NSArray *labels = @[ self.label, self.label1, self.label2, self.label3, self.label4 ];
UIFont *font = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
UIFont *bold = [utilClass boldFontSize:12];

for (UILabel *label in labels) {
    label.font = font;
}

if (newPosition == 100) {
    labels[0].font = boldFont;
} else if (newPosition == 200) {
    labels[1].font = boldFont;
} else if (newPosition == -100) {
    labels[2].font = boldFont;
} else if (newPosition == -200) {
    labels[3].font = boldFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, less code, especially less repeated code is better:Less chance of an error wjem initially written and less change of an error later when it is revised.

Something like this makes it clear what is happening, that only one thing is being changed per newPosition.

```
UIFont *baseFont = [utilClass fontWithSize:12];
UIFont *boldFont = [utilClass boldFontSize:12];

self.label.font  = baseFont;
self.label1.font = baseFont;
self.label2.font = baseFont;
self.label3.font = baseFont;
self.label4.font = baseFont;

switch (newPosition) {
    case 100:
        self.label.font = boldFont;
        break;
    case 200:
        self.label1.font = boldFont;
        break;
    case -100:
        self.label2.font  = boldFont;
        break;
    case -200:
        self.label3.font = boldFont;
}
```